# joint.setTheme is not a function in JointJS-Rappid

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jointjs, rappid

I am trying to set theme for my application.I included the dependent files in the order jquery,lodash,backbone,graphlib,dagre,keyboard,rappid and localJs file. when i tried to set the theme with joint.setTheme(dark); it throws an error in the console Joint.setTheme is not a function. I went through the rappid documentation [Rappid documentation UI](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/rappid/v2.0/index.html#ui)

I included rappid.js and rappid.css files instead of including individually other joint.ui.xxx.js files in-order to get access to all the features that rappid provides.

the sample JS code looks like this [joint.setTheme error code](https://jsfiddle.net/2vo16dke/).
How can i set the theme specific to the code written in the fiddle below? please help...

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i need Rappid for application styling. What i found is joint.setTheme is available in rappid V2.0 i was using older version(found with joint.version in the console). When i update rappid.min.css and rappid.min.js to V2.0 it is working. @vt your example is impressive. Thanks for that and appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to include rappid for themes, as the setThemes is part of the JointJS core. Also make sure `joint` is exposed to  global namespace when you tried the joint.setTheme in browser console.

For inspiration please visit setTheme fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vtalas/2kubzakn/